Pin Constraints
I'm slowly learning how to use blender after years of Inventor and Solidworks. We generally use blender for promotional material. Currently I am trying to get a simple animation to work. The main yellow circular section is lowered over the grey bit. The hook a pinnerd/bolted at the top. I want to constrain the hook to have rotation only around that pin hole at the top. Is this possible? or am I stuck in a CAD modelling mindset?


The easiest way is to align an empty or a bone to the arm, put it in the location of the desired pivot point, lock all transform parameters except the desired rotation an set the arm child of the empty, so that rotating the empty will rotate the arm with constrained axis and pivot.
Use the snapping functions to align the empty (i.e. face project and align rotation to target).

